# Device that is just mouse buttons and scroll wheels

Tags: mice, assistive-technology

## Question

I'm searching for a device that is simply a box that acts as a USB mouse, with these

A web-search for "mouse button box" returns pages with this $125 assistive  technology device, but it's not quite what I'm looking for, and is a bit pricey.

[image]

## Specifications

1. Contains hardware for left/right-click. (may have more buttons)
2. Contains hardware for independent vertical/horizontal scroll wheels. (doesn't have to be a traditional scroll wheel, could be a spinner/knob/fly-wheel)
3. Is ergonomically designed remain stationary, with emphasis on easy of pushing buttons and using scroll wheel devices.
4. Which means, it probably does not contain hardware for actually moving the mouse cursor. That function would be performed with a separate piece of hardware.

except it does not have a feature to move the mouse-cursor. Is

## Workarounds that I've tried

I've tried remapping keyboard keys to mouse clicks with programs like [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) and [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys), but the solution isn't great. It's buggy and unresponsive at time.

Comment: Since it's assistive tech, it costs more.  That's because health insurance can cover it, and when insurance can cover something, prices on that something get inflated drastically (rendering insurance nothing but a legalized protection racket, if you ask me).  After 5 years in software that managed healthcare contracts, I can tell you that anything like this has its price determined first by the maximum amount they can get from the insurance companies.  You might want to look into gaming keyboards; there are supplemental ones for the left hand that can be mapped to do what you're asking.

Comment: Seems super niche. Have you thought about doing it yourself with an Arduino? It probably won't be to hard or expensive.